# How to fix 'browser' being undefined when importing protractor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

When importing protrator in an Angualr application I try to use the function `browser.waitForAngularEnabled`.

When I run the code I get the error:

**E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForAngularEnabled' of undefined**

I am importing the browser in this way

```js
   const { browser } = require('protractor');
```

When I click through to the protractor module in VS code I can see the browser object in there but in runtime this error is thrown.

Comment: Are you setting true or false for this property?   browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) ?

Comment: i'm setting it to false

Answer (score 1):

In Protractor, you are provided with a global browser object. So you don't need to require it, the browser object is accessible without requiring it.

Solution:
Just remove the require and it will work.

Note:
You have to import it only if you are working with typescript.